# Why doesn't AWS SAM Node.js sample application work on Arch Linux LTS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, archlinux, aws-sam-cli

AWS SAM sample Node.js application doesn’t work on my Arch Linux LTS environment.

- OS: Arch Linux 4.19.37-1-lts
- SAM version: 0.15.0
- Docker version: 18.09.5-ce, build e8ff056dbc

The error can be reproduced with following steps.

1. Initialize a sample Node.js application.

```
$ sam init --runtime nodejs
[+] Initializing project structure...

Project generated: ./sam-app

Steps you can take next within the project folder
===================================================
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction --event event.json
[*] Start API Gateway locally: sam local start-api

Read sam-app/README.md for further instructions

[*] Project initialization is now complete
```

2. Start local api.

```
$ cd sam-app
$ sam local start-api
2019-04-30 17:58:36 Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2019-04-30 17:58:36 Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello [GET]
2019-04-30 17:58:36 You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2019-04-30 17:58:36  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

3. Make a http request to **http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello** with curl in another terminal. The response is "*Internal server error*".

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello
{"message":"Internal server error"}
```

4. A 502 error is recorded in the server log.

```
2019-04-30 17:59:20 Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs8.10)

Fetching lambci/lambda:nodejs8.10 Docker container image......
2019-04-30 17:59:22 Mounting /var/work/sam-app/hello-world as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
2019-04-30 17:59:30 Function returned an invalid response (must include one of: body, headers or statusCode in the response object). Response received: 
2019-04-30 17:59:30 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Apr/2019 17:59:30] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 502 -
```

Does anybody know the cause of this issue?

**Further investigation:**

I tried to run the node command manually in docker interctive mode, then I got "*Illegal instruction*" error as below. Need more investigation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by installing Node.js 8.10 via yum during docker image build phase and using `/usr/bin/node` instead of original `/var/lang/bin/node`.

**Changes in Dockerfile of lambci/lambda:nodejs8.10**

https://github.com/y15e/docker-lambda/commit/3ec7f0fe8086b6fdcd15c92b9976b91072108f3f

[image]

You can build above modified docker image by following steps.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:y15e/docker-lambda.git
$ cd docker-lambda/nodejs8.10/run
$ docker build --no-cache -t lambci/lambda:nodejs8.10 .
```

Then run `sam local start-api --skip-pull-image`. Don’t forget `--skip-pull-image` option otherwise the original docker image will be downloaded and the above changes will be reverted.